# I am trying to run the update manager

Tags: updates

The package system is broken
check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
I dont think I am running third party repositories...but am unsure how to find out

Answer (score 0):

To check if you have any third-party repositories, you can follow these steps:

1. Open up the "Software Sources" application from the Dash.
2. Click on the tab labelled "Other Software".

Any third-party repositories you have enabled will appear here.  You can uncheck any repositories you'd like to disable.  When doing so you will be prompted for your password.